# (How) Can an android virtual device use the local computer's internet?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have a server running on the network my computer is on. Is there a way to allow the virtual device to use this same network and access the server? The virtual device won't let me toggle the wifi (probably because it doesn't have one). The only options I see that look right are:

"Wireless & network settings" --> "Mobile networks" --> "Access point names".

I'm not sure what to fill into all these fields though. If someone has an example of all the fields that are necessary to use the local computers internet, I'd appreciate it.

The virtual device is emulating my Droid X (API 2.2). I'm not looking for answers on how to communicate with the server but to get on the net and possibly a simple test to verify I'm on (right now I'm just using the ConnectivityManager to check)

[image: Edit access point GUI]

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

As noted therein:

> "Each instance of the emulator runs
>   behind a virtual router/firewall
>   service that isolates it from your
>   development machine's network
>   interfaces and settings and from the
>   internet. An emulated device can not
>   see your development machine or other
>   emulator instances on the network.
>   Instead, it sees only that it is
>   connected through Ethernet to a
>   router/firewall."

So you'll need to use the server's public IP (as opposed to it's local network IP).

Comment: Thanks, that link had a table that helped

Comment: 127.0.0.1 would be invalid. That would normally be localhost if used from your machine, but localhost for Android devices and emulators is 10.0.2.2. Either way, localhost isn't what you want. Glad the link helped. Good luck!

Comment: Given link is broken

Answer (score 9):

you dont need to do so much thing.

Just use your machine's ip to achieve this.

Suppose your machine(server) ip is `192.168.1.1`

Then from your application just use `http://192.168.1.1/your_appliction/webpage`

If you want to access `http://localhost/` just use `http://10.0.2.2/`

Comment: The server I need to access isn't on my local machine. It's on the network

Comment: Not a problem..get the ip of the server and use it.

Answer (score 1):

To enable/toggle Wi-fi you need to go the `Dev Tools` option. That should do.