# How to connect to AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to write my own Android http server. It's quite OK but I have a problem with my AVD. I don't want to download my app to phone every time I want to test changes. I would like to connect to my app via AVD.
To get the IP address I'm using this function:

```
private String getLocalIpAddress() {


        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

on my phone everything works but when I run my app on AVD it shows ip: 10.0.2.15
and I'm unable to connect to it.
Is there any way to connect to my app running on AVD?
If it matters my app uses port 8080.

Answer (score 7):

Telnet into the device (assuming it is on port 5554):

telnet localhost 5554

At the Android console prompt use a redirect:

redir add tcp:8080:8080

Pointing your browser to 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'  should now send, and receive to the AVD.

Courtesy of:
http://www.rhill.co.uk/?p=35

Comment: It's unclear, where the 'redir' command needs to come from, it's not present in the latest images.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the answer to your problem directly, I do know that when connecting FROM an AVD TO your computer, you have to use 10.0.2.2 because your AVD is essentially behind another "router". It doesn't get a local lan IP from your router. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224474/how-can-an-android-virtual-device-use-the-local-computers-internet) question for more information. From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) link, he quotes:

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall
>   service that isolates it from your development machine's network
>   interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device can
>   not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the
>   network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet
>   to a router/firewall.