# Sending file to localhost from Android Emulator - 301 Error response from localhost / PHP File issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-301

I am trying to connect the android emulator to my localhost (xampp) and send a file to a folder.

I am using the code from slott - [wrapping the code up in an Async task to avoid threading errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-to-send-a-file-in-android-from-mobile-to-server-using-http)

and calling it via:

```
new AsyncHttpPostTask("http://10.0.2.2/android").execute(new File(myFile));
```

myFile is a valid file with some text

the folder "android" exists directly under the "xampp/htdocs" folder on the c drive

I have added the internet permission in the manifest

I have deleted my AVD and created a new one

XAMPP is running, the path is valid if i open it in a browser e.g. `http://localhost/android`

After executing the code, i get a **"301 Moved Permanently"** response from the localhost server

Any ideas on what i have done wrong or how i can investigate further?

==EDIT

I was missing the php file on my path. I am using the following PHP

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
  move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile'] ['name']);
} else {
  echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
  echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
  print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

I havent used PHP before however i am able to connect now but getting the following error in the response:

**Undefined index in the server.php file**

Comment: If i try to send the file to http://10.0.2.2 i dont recieve a response from the server

Comment: whats the code to receive the file from the server side ?

Comment: php code added to question

Comment: where do you set values for the variables you use for indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my PHP code to use [MultipartEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr)

The emulator was crashing after the PHP changes but this was resolved by deleting my AVD and creating a new one. In addition i restarted my localhost server

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST the **data**, but you will also need a script (probably php since you're using XAMPP) written to accept the post data and save it to that location.

EDIT:

I recommend writing a form to interact with your php script to test if the problem is with your server accepting files.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/android/server.php"; method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /> 
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> 
</form>
```

Make that page to test uploading files from your computer. Also try it in your AVDs browser.

What I think is your problem is that you're using localhost. You probably need to use your servers public IP address. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224558/1629749

Comment: thank you yes, i forgot to add the server.php file to my path however this results in an issue with the php file. I have edited my question