# How to implement websockets i android?

Tags: android, node.js, web-services, mongoose, websocket

Hello I am trying to make an android pic sharing app like insta, but it doesnt work efficiently every time a user request hashtag like #pic it goes to server run query nd get result, it make process repetitive and slow. is there any other way to get this done  like using websockets for a case if person has followed 5 people whenever someone add a new post it will just inform to all the people who are listening to it

Comment: You can use websockets, but push notifications would probably be cleaner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Connecting to Node.js server using Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223189/android-app-connecting-to-node-js-server-using-socket-io)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223189/android-app-connecting-to-node-js-server-using-socket-io/36908846

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for your reply. If I go with push notifications but still the problem persists, if i need to implement this like a user  follow 100 people and i want to display recent posts to him how it will be done if i query simply using mongoose and paginate it for infinite scroll in my app it will take too much time and for every page it will search from all post  from database