# AnyChart android refreshing a chart

Tags: android, kotlin, anychart

I am using anychart library for android to display a pie chart, it gets the data from a mysql using volley and a node JS api to facilitate the crud operation

I am just facing a problem refresing the chart when new data is available from the data base.
I used Log.d to make sure the data is actually being updated it, I checked anycharts github and tried the solutions they listed, mainly that I just need to set the data again with the new data, that didn't work
Please any help is greatly appreciated.
I even tried creating a button and try to set the graph with complety new and hardcoded data. but that didn't work, I tried to use gone and visible and that didn't work

here is my code:

```
 package com.dana.baizaty_frontend.fragments

import Transaction
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.anychart.APIlib
import com.anychart.AnyChart
import com.anychart.AnyChartView
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.ValueDataEntry
import com.anychart.enums.Align
import com.anychart.enums.LegendLayout
import com.dana.baizaty_frontend.R
import com.dana.baizaty_frontend.singleton.AppSingleton
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_pfm.*


class PFM : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


//        val anyChartView: AnyChartView? = any_chart_view

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
//        createChart()

        var v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pfm, container, false)


        return v


    }




    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//        getTransactions()
        button.setOnClickListener{
            updateChart()
        }

    }


    override fun onStart() {


        super.onStart()
        getTransactions()

        Toast.makeText(context, "testing", "testing".length).show()
    }
    fun createChart (data1: MutableList<DataEntry>
    ) {
//        var anyChartView: AnyChartView? = any_chart_view

//        APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(any_chart_view)
//        any_chart_view.clear()
        any_chart_view.visibility=View.GONE


        any_chart_view.setProgressBar(progress_bar)
        var pie = AnyChart.pie3d()
//        anyChartView?.setProgressBar(progress_bar)


//        data.add(ValueDataEntry("Restarant", 30))
//        data.add(ValueDataEntry("transportation", 23))
//        data.add(ValueDataEntry("cafe", 10))
        Log.d("catagor3",data1.toString())

        pie.data(data1)
        pie.title("spending")
        pie.labels().position("outside")
        pie.legend().title().enabled(true)

        pie.legend()
            .position("center-bottom")
            .itemsLayout(LegendLayout.HORIZONTAL)
            .align(Align.CENTER);

        any_chart_view?.setChart(pie);
        any_chart_view.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        data1.clear()

    }
    fun updateChart(){
        var data1 = mutableListOf<DataEntry>()
        data1.add(ValueDataEntry("Restarant", 30))
        data1.add(ValueDataEntry("transportation", 23))
        data1.add(ValueDataEntry("cafe", 10))
        var pie=AnyChart.pie3d()
        any_chart_view.setChart(pie)

    }

    fun getTransactions() {
        var data = mutableListOf<DataEntry>()
        any_chart_view.invalidate()
        var queue = AppSingleton.instance.getQueue(context)
        var transactionsRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            AppSingleton.instance.getBaseUrl() + "transactions/3",
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Success case

                var transactionList = Gson().fromJson<List<Transaction>>(response, object :
                    TypeToken<List<Transaction>>() {}.type)

                var catagories = mutableListOf<String>()
                var values = mutableListOf<Double>()

                transactionList.forEach {
//                    Log.d("catgor",it.toString())
                    if (catagories.contains(it.catagorie)) {
                        var idx = catagories.indexOf(it.catagorie)
//                        Log.d("catgor1",idx.toString())
//                        Log.d("catgor2",catagories.toString())

                        values[idx] += it.amount

                    }else{
                        catagories.add(it.catagorie)
                        values.add(it.amount)
                        var idx=catagories.indexOf(it.catagorie)
//                        values[idx]=0.0
                    }
                }
                Log.d("catagor",catagories.toString())
                Log.d("catagor",values.toString())

                catagories.forEach{
                    var idx=catagories.indexOf(it)
                    data.add(ValueDataEntry(it,values[idx]))
                }
                Log.d("catagor3",data.toString())

                createChart(data)
                data.clear()
                Log.d("catagor3",data.toString())


            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                // Error case
            })
        queue?.add(transactionsRequest)
    }
}
```

and here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.PFM">

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="389dp"
        android:layout_height="333dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/any_chart_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to update the chart with new data is to make it active and apply new data. 
For details, check the following issue threads:
[issue 1](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/108)
[issue 2](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/97#issuecomment-498983079)

Answer (score -1):

Directly it's not possible , You need to add Socket for it SocketIO for it. So you need to integrate socketIO server side and client side both .
Please check this :-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229881/11393364

Comment: any_chart_view.invalidate(); call this code inside your UpdateChart method after any_chart_view.setChart(pie) .