# Connecting my rest API with Android Studio using Retrofit by emulator

Tags: java, android, rest, android-emulator, retrofit2

I have two questions:

- Why am I getting null for the URL?
- Am I connecting my localhost to my Android Studio emulator correctly?

If not then how can I connect my Android Studio to my local host?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";
    TextView  text_name_1, text_city_1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        text_name_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_name_1);
        text_name_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_city_1);
        Button ButtonArray= (Button) findViewById(R.id.RetrofitArray);
        ButtonArray.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View VisibleArray = findViewById(R.id.RetrofitArray);
                VisibleArray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getRetrofitArray();
            }
        });

    }


    void getRetrofitArray() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayAPI.class);

        Call<List<Healthinfo>> call = service.getHealthDetails();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Healthinfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Healthinfo>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                try {

                    List<Healthinfo> StudentData = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < StudentData.size(); i++) {

                        if (i == 0) {
                            text_name_1.setText("UserName  :  " + StudentData.get(i). getUsername());
                            text_city_1.setText("city  : " + StudentData.get(i).getCity());
                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RetorfitArrayAPI**

```
import retrofit.http.GET;
public interface RetrofitArrayAPI {

    /*
     * Retrofit get annotation with our URL
     * And our method that will return us details of student.
    */

    @GET("/try/salma/123")
    Call<List<Healthinfo>> getHealthDetails();

}
```

I have already checked my REST API in postman and I am getting the following output:

```
[{"user_id":"8","username":"salma","email":"salma@hotmail.com","birthday":"2017-01-12","gender":"","skills":"","country":"Pak","city":"Peshawar","number":"8967","password":"123","cpassword":"123","img":""}]
```

I am getting the following error in my Android emulator:

```
01-20 18:28:34.419 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-20 18:28:34.421 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth I/art: Late-enabling JIT
01-20 18:28:34.445 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
01-20 18:28:34.922 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth-2/lib/x86
01-20 18:28:35.843 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 836.103ms
01-20 18:28:35.984 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 49.509ms
01-20 18:28:36.340 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 49.543ms
01-20 18:28:36.941 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 234.781ms
01-20 18:28:37.263 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 69.193ms
01-20 18:28:38.013 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.492ms
01-20 18:28:38.410 2762-2828/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-20 18:28:38.470 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa44ab260, tid 2762
01-20 18:28:38.593 2762-2828/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-20 18:28:38.669 2762-2828/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 18:28:38.669 2762-2828/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xadadf2a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-20 18:28:38.793 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.637ms
01-20 18:28:39.266 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.926ms
01-20 18:28:42.839 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 58.303ms
01-20 18:28:42.845 2762-2762/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 18:28:44.157 2762-2769/com.example.fahadpirzada.motherhealth W/art: Suspending all threads took: 29.957ms
```

Comment: i think you have not set baseUrl thats why this error is occured

Comment: i have declared "String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";  "

Comment: Then in @GET  remove localhost:8000

Comment: still same issue :(

Comment: Which version of retrofit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000";
```

and

```
@GET("/try/salma/123")
```

Comment: still getting lots of error . I think that somehow my android is not setting connection with my localhost through emulator

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Comment: @fahadpirzada You are right, you can't connect to server from local net.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224474/how-can-an-android-virtual-device-use-the-local-computers-internet